# Is there equivalent API for Vulkan to do cuEventRecord & cuEventQuery?

Tags: vulkan

cuEventQuery and cuEventRecord are async APIs from CUDA for querying whether some tasks in queue has been finished or not. I have the same requirement in Vulkan but I don't want to use Vulkan Barrier API which works slow.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you need to synchronize between the same queue, queue-to-host, or between different queues, your options are:

- Fences – https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-khr-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-fences – can be used for synchronisation *between the host and a queue* and be waited on via `vkWaitForFences()` and queried for their status via `vkGetFenceStatus()`, and
- Events – https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-khr-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-events – can be used for sync *in the same queue* or queue-to-host, although they *cannot* be waited on by the host as fences can, but can be queried for their status via `vkGetEventStatus()`

Both are more heavyweight than barries, with events being the most lightweight one, and closest to the CUDA event API.

Comment: "*Fences - [...] can be used for synchronisation between queues*" No, they can't. A fence cannot be waited on by a queue; they can only be waited on by the host. Fences are for queue-to-host synchronization. Semaphores are for queue-to-queue synchronization.

Comment: You mean, "both are more heavyweight", no?

Comment: Thanks, you are both right of course. Sorry for being sloppy when writing this, it's corrected now.